# For-do loop with accordion in C# MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I'm using Twitter bootstrap's Accordion code in which then I aim to switch theirs with mine.

In my project I am going to have this structure:

```
Main 2
 - Sub 1
 - Sub 2
 - Sub 3
Main 1
- Sub 1
- Sub 2
- Sub 3
```

And these increase according to the number there is in a certain database (if there are 4 for example, it will go up to Main 4)
Sub1,Sub2,Sub3.... are other Accordions, so I have to have an outer accordion and inner accordions

I am trying to use this code:

```
    @for (int j = 1; j < number; j++ )
{ 
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion@j">

    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">@j. What is HTML?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @j
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>

}
```

where `number` is how the number from my db

This though does not work. The accordion doesn't work and instead gives me only 2 open divs. The @j changes number accordingly though

any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
id="accordion@j">
```

with

```
id="@("accordion" + j)"
```

Comment: There is a slight problem though, I cannot control the Accordion, I try to open the 2nd one, but it just closes the first one.